# How to get multiple occurences of a pattern between two definite endpoints

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
   bar foo,
   foo bar
) DISTRIBUTED BY
```

I would like to get all column definitions from this string. I tried:

```
my_string.scan /CREATE TABLE .*\n([^\n]*?)\n.*DISTRIBUTED BY/
```

But it does not return with the desired values (`["bar foo,", "foo bar"]`) . Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point of [scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method is each new match begins when the last one ends:

```
a = "cruel world"
a.scan(/.../)        #=> ["cru", "el ", "wor"]
```

So you need to define your pattern so that it will match both at the beginning and in the middle of the string. Needless to say, that won't be easy to build such a look-behind expression.

But I wonder will this be enough to your specific goals:

```
s = <<HR
CREATE TABLE foobar (
   bar foo,
   foo bar
) DISTRIBUTED BY}
HR

ax = s.scan /\s+(.+?)(?:,\n|\n\))/
#=> [["bar foo"], ["foo bar"]]
```

As you see, I didn't try to match `CREATE TABLE` here, assuming the string has the query ready.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used if not exactly this, but a similar approach doing it in multiple steps. Beside being easier to program, it's also easier to understand this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
/CREATE TABLE .*\n((?:.*\n)+).*DISTRIBUTED BY/
```

`(?:.*\n)` matches an individual line, so `((?:.*\n)+)` captures one or more lines in group #1.  The linefeed at the end of the last line (`foo bar`) is included, but you can delete that at the same time you clean up the commas (e.g. from `bar foo,`).

If you're thinking about doing anything more complicated, think about using an actual parser; regex do not play well with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the way to go.

```
my_string.split[1..-2].map(&:strip)
```